# imacros: run bookmarklet code (javascript) in imacros?

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have this code from a bookmarklet and I want to use it in a imacros script but I don't know how.

The script clicks multiple (javascript?) buttons on a site which I can't get to automate with imacros 
code:

```js
!function(){var e=function(t,n,a){return(e=document.getElementsByClassName?function(e,t,n){n=n||document;for(var a,o=n.getElementsByClassName(e),l=t?RegExp("\\b"+t+"\\b","i"):null,u=[],r=0,c=o.length;c>r;r+=1)a=o[r],(!l||l.test(a.nodeName))&&u.push(a);return u}:document.evaluate?function(e,t,n){t=t||"*",n=n||document;for(var a,o,l=e.split(" "),u="",r="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",c=document.documentElement.namespaceURI===r?r:null,s=[],m=0,d=l.length;d>m;m+=1)u+='[contains(concat(" ", @class, " "), " '+l[m]+' ")]';try{a=document.evaluate(".//"+t+u,n,c,0,null)}catch(i){a=document.evaluate(".//"+t+u,n,null,0,null)}for(;o=a.iterateNext();)s.push(o);return s}:function(e,t,n){t=t||"*",n=n||document;for(var a,o,l=e.split(" "),u=[],r="*"===t&&n.all?n.all:n.getElementsByTagName(t),c=[],s=0,m=l.length;m>s;s+=1)u.push(RegExp("(^|\\s)"+l[s]+"(\\s|$)"));for(var d=0,i=r.length;i>d;d+=1){a=r[d],o=!1;for(var v=0,h=u.length;h>v&&(o=u[v].test(a.className),o);v+=1);o&&c.push(a)}return c})(t,n,a)},t=function(e,t){if(-1==e.className.indexOf("x-grid3-row-selected")){var n=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");n.initMouseEvent("mousedown",!0,!0,window,0,0,0,0,0,t,t,t,t,0,null),e.dispatchEvent(n);var a=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");a.initMouseEvent("click",!0,!0,window,0,0,0,0,0,t,t,t,t,0,null),e.dispatchEvent(a)}};try{var n=document.createElement("script");n.textContent="window.fua();",(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(n),n.parentNode.removeChild(n);var a=e("x-grid3-rows","div",document.getElementById("tweepiGridDiv"));if(a.length<=0)return;t(a[0],!1),t(a[a.length-1],!0)}catch(o){alert("Something went wrong. Please make sure you are on a Tweepi.com page! "+o)}}();
```

I tried putting it in a name.js file and run it but I get following error:

> Something went wrong. Please make sure you are on a Tweepi.com page!
>   ReferenceError: document is not defined

I hope anyone can help me since I'm a bit lost and try & error doesn't work anymore for me at this point.

Comment: Before your code write this: `var document=window.document;` save it and try to play the script again.

Comment: wow thank you, that did the trick :D - would you mind commenting the code? i know what the code does but i am not really clear how it does it. if i can understand it i could use this method in the future for other stuff

Comment: That’s time expensive and I’m not confident that will be able to understand fully the code and clearly explain it with my English.